# convert data to comma separate

Tags: python, shell

I have a scenario where in my directory there are 10 files.

Each file as one columnar record like below;

**file1:**

```
A
B
C
D
```

**file2:**

```
C
D
F
G
```

2 files means

**Expected Output:**

- file 1 data should be: `"A","B","C","D"` -> write to new file: A1.txt
- file 2 data should be: `"C","D","F","G"` -> write to new file: A2.txt

I tried this command, it worked partially but adding last value with `','` command

```
sed -e 's/.*/\"&\"/' /d/file1.txt | tr '\n' ','
```

giving below output but comma at end which is extra

```
"A","B","C","D",
```

Note: The file might contain blank lines/space/tabs at the end
that should be ignored.

How to write the same script in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `paste`.

Also, since you're writing CSV, you want to escape any double quotes that exist in the original data

```sh
sed 's/"/""/g; s/.*/"&"/' filename | paste -s -d,
```

---

[ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) is handy for quick scripts: the bundled `csv` module means you don't have to worry about the edge cases.

```sh
ruby -rcsv -e '
  data = File.new(ARGV.shift).readlines(chomp: true)
  puts CSV.generate_line(data)
' file
```

Comment: is it possible to write in same file without creating new file